# ReactJS <form> onSubmit forward to new component and page

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I might be misunderstanding React, in which case I welcome suggestions to rearchitect my site.

**My desired behaviour** is after submitting the `SimulationForm` the user is then forwarded to another component called `SimulationResults`. This will take an *id* used to send a database query.

**The current behaviour** is that the simulation  doesn't forward at all after submitting, staying on the same page.

Ideally, so that the user can easily return to the results in the future I would like it if the simulation *id* could be passed as a url path parameter to the results page, intead of going through the submit form again.

I have an `index.js` that looks like this:

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import SimulationForm from './simulation_form'
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<SimulationForm />, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

And `simulation_form.js` like this:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class SimulationForm extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      simulationName: "",
      ...
      ...
    };

   this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
   ...
  }
...
...
   handleSubmit(event) {
     event.preventDefault();

     ...
     ...
   }
...
...
return(
      <form id="simulationForm" className="centered" onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
        <label>Simulation name:</label>
        <input type="text" placeholder="enter name here" name="simulationName" value={this.state.simulationName} onChange={this.handleChange} />
...
...
    );
  }
}
```

At the end of the *handleSubmit* function I've tried:

```
return <SimulationResults />;
```

and

```
ReactDOM.render(<SimulationResults />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

to no success. It's clear I don't understand how React wants me to set this up. I've been reading the docs and the web but can't find any examples of what I want to achieve. I'm also unsure as to how I pass state (an *id* string) to the results component from the form component.

`simualation_results.js`:

```js
import React from 'react';

export default class SimulationResults extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      simId: ""
    }
  }
...
...
render() {
    return <form id="simulationResults" className="centered" onSubmit={this.queryDatabase}>
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter simId" name="simId" value={this.state.simId} onChange={this.handleChange}  />
      <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
    </form>
  }
```

Comment: You need to install react-router for the "redirect" functionality.  Each "route" will load some component.

Comment: Ah I see. Thank you i.brod !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@i.brod pointed me in the direction of [react-router](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start) to achieve what I wanted.

1. `npm install react-router-dom`
2. I then added a `<Router>` to my `index.js`:

```js
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Switch,
  Route,
  useParams
} from "react-router-dom";

ReactDOM.render(<Index />, document.getElementById('root'));

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <Router>
      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <SimulationForm />
          </Route>
          <Route path="/results/:id?">
            <Results />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Where `path="/results/:id?"` matches `/results` as well as `/results/{anything}`.

3. I made my SimulationResults component a function instead of a standalone component.

```js
function Results() {
  let { id } = useParams();

  queryDatabase(id);

  return (
    <div className="centered" >
      <h3 id="results-header">waiting...</h3>
      <form id="simulationResults" onSubmit={(e) => {e.preventDefault(); queryDatabase(document.getElementById("simHash").value);}}>
        <input id="simHash" type="text" placeholder="enter simHash" />
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </form>
    </div>
  )
}
```

SimulationForm is still a component:

```js
export default class SimulationForm extends React.Component {
...
}
```

4. To redirect from `/` to `/results:id` at the end of the the form's onSubmit I added:

```js
window.location.href = '/results/' + id
```